# How to Set What $(this) Refers To?

Tags: jquery

jQuery noob here.

I have a jQuery handler that makes use of `$(this)`. Is there a way for me to call this handler from another handler and specify what element `$(this)` refers to?

Comment: Your question has many hidden questions to answer.  Can you show the specific handler and caller and explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do that using `.apply` or `.call` javascript functions.

Like:

```
handlerName.apply(newScope, [param1, param2]);
```

or

```
handlerName.call(newScope, param1, param2);
```

where `newScope` is what `this` will refer to in that `handlerName`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, `$(this)` in jQuery is simply making sure that what's pointed to by `this` -- which is to say, the current object in context -- has all the jQuery methods.  But it's still just an object reference.  It sounds like you want to wrap it up in a closure and pass it to the next handler.

An example of the actual code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at using the [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method as well.